# How can I change the Category Product to Static Block in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, static-block

How can I change the Category **Product to Static Block**  in magento 2 from back end?

I check it in **Product -> Categories** and select the one category and click **Display Setting**

then change the **Display Mode** in ***Product Only to Static Block only***

where I choose the **Static Block** there is no option for choose block?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to backend,

Go Content tab and choose static block from **Add CMS Block**.

You can select from **Content** section.

[image]

Comment: I added after that i deploy that content ?.

Comment: i dont understand your query

Comment: how to add page Category?.

Comment: have you create Page Category block inside Content -> Blocks? You can only add static block only using above method. You cant add page or category.

Comment: ok.. it passable to add the page in any other method